# draw an Ellipsoid given its quaderatic equation in Matlab

Tags: geometry, matlab

How can I draw an ellipsoid in Matlab with following equation:

$aX^2 + bY^2 + cZ^2 + d XY+e XZ +f YZ +gX +hY+iZ=R^2$

with (for example) 
$a=1;
b=2;
c=3;
d=4;
e=5;
f=6;
g=7;
h=8;
i=9;
R^2=10.$

Comment: You can just use `isosurface(X, Y, Z, a*X.^2 + b*Y.^2 + c*Z.^2 + d*X.*Y + e*X.*Z + f*Y.*Z + g*X + h*Y + i*Z, r^2)` after creating `[X, Y, Z]` using `meshgrid`. http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isosurface.html

Answer (score 2):

Since the question's been bumped by [the Community bot](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) yet again, I'm posting my comment as an answer:

You can just use [isosurface](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isosurface.html).

```
[X, Y, Z] = meshgrid(-5:5, -5:5, -5:5);
isosurface(X, Y, Z, a*X.^2 + b*Y.^2 + c*Z.^2 + d*X.*Y + e*X.*Z + f*Y.*Z + g*X + h*Y + i*Z, r^2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The equation you give is of the form $\alpha Z^2 + \beta Z + \gamma = 0$, so given the values of all the coefficients along with grid of $(X,Y)$ pairs, we can use the quadratic formula to solve for the two values of $Z$ that satisfy the equation:

```
[x,y] = meshgrid( (-50:0.1:50), (-50:0.1:50)' );

quadsoln1 = @(a,b,c)( ( -b + sqrt(b.^2 - 4*a.*c) ) ./ (2*a) );
quadsoln2 = @(a,b,c)( ( -b - sqrt(b.^2 - 4*a.*c) ) ./ (2*a) );

a = 1;
b = 2;
c = 3;
d = 4;
e = 5;
f = 6;
g = 7;
h = 8;
i = 9;
R = sqrt(10);

z1 = quadsoln1( c, e*x + f*y + i, a*x.^2 + b*y.^2 + d*x.*y + g*x + h*y - R );
z2 = quadsoln2( c, e*x + f*y + i, a*x.^2 + b*y.^2 + d*x.*y + g*x + h*y - R );
```

To plot the above, you can use `plot3` to plot points or try something like `mesh` or `surf`. The latter two, however, are quite memory intensive and seem just unstable in general.

Answer (score -1):

You can treat the ellipsoid as a transformed sphere, with points $v$ given by an equation of the form $v^t M v = 1$. Because the matrix $M$ will turn out to be symmetric with nonnegative eigenvalues, it has a square root, say $S$, so that $S^t S = M$. Then the equation becomes $v^t S^t S v = 1$, so $Sv$ is a vector $u$ satisfying $u^t u = 1$, i.e., a point of the unit sphere. Letting $v = S^{-1}u$, you're done. here's the code:

```
function ellipsoid(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, j, R)
M = (1/R^2) * [
    a d e g;
    0 b f h;
    0 0 c j;
    0 0 0 1];
M = (M + M')/2;
S = M^0.5

n = 30;
[th, ph] = meshgrid(linspace(0, 2*pi, n), linspace(0, pi, n));
spherepoints = zeros(4, n, n);
spherepoints(1, :,:) = cos(th) .* sin(ph);
spherepoints(2, :,:) = sin(th) .* sin(ph);
spherepoints(3, :,:) = cos(ph);
spherepoints(4, :, :) = 1;
sp = reshape(spherepoints, 4, []); 
epoints = S \ sp;
epoints = reshape(epoints, 4, n, n);

surf(squeeze(epoints(1, :,:)),...
    squeeze(epoints(2,:,:)),...
    squeeze(epoints(3,:,:)));
set(gca, 'DataAspectRatio', [1,1,1]);
figure(gcf);
```

Thanks to the anonymous reviewer who noted that I'd written `epoints = S * sp` instead of `S \ sp`.